How can i find out records from a column in a table in Snowflake which does not have any alphabets as well any number?
I have a table and within that in a specific column, i need to find out the records which are having characters anything except an alphabets or numbers.
I tried using regex as
'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]'
Am i doing it correctly?
I have a table and within that in a specific column, i need to find out the records which are having characters anything except an alphabets or numbers.

Hi - does it give the correct answer? If it does then you are doing it correctly

So your REGEXP is correct, accept Snowflake does an odd thing with REGEXP command and implicitly put start/end anchors, as noted in the doc's

The function implicitly anchors a pattern at both ends (i.e. '' automatically becomes '^$', and 'ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$'). To match any string starting with ABC, the pattern would be 'ABC.*'.

So you need to put wild match tokens in:
select 
    $1 as str
    ,str regexp '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]' as r1
    ,str regexp '.*[^A-Za-z0-9 ].*' as r2
from values
    ('abcd'), -- good
    ('123'), -- good
    ('abc123'), -- good
    ('!@#$'), -- bad
    ('a!b@c#1$3') -- bad




STR
R1
R1




abcd
FALSE
FALSE


123
FALSE
FALSE


abc123
FALSE
FALSE


!@#$
FALSE
TRUE


a!b@c#1$3
FALSE
TRUE



so then you can use that in a WHERE clause
